# changing default file location for vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, file-io

i would like to be able to set the change the default file location. for example if i do a filestream on a "file.txt", i want it to look by default in the desktop. is there somewhere in the settings of vb.net express 2008 where i can change this default location of working with files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[System.IO.Directory.SetCurrentDirectory()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.setcurrentdirectory.aspx)